# Can't execute the event ajaxStart()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to change the state of the button **to disabled** when i call a php script using ajax(with jquery). i send all the information in the database and get a return but the **ajaxStart** can't be executed. How can i solve the problem to change the state of the button?
Here is the code:
**HTML AND JAVASCRIPT**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $("#load").hide();
  var name;
  var age;
  var post
  $(".formulaire").submit(function() {
    name = $("#name").val();
    age = $("#age").val();
    post = $("#post").val();
    $.post('sequence.php', {
      u_name: name,
      age: age,
      post: post
    }, dats);
    $("#bouton").ajaxStart(function() { // Nous ciblons l'élément #loading qui est caché
      $("#bouton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      console.log("*********");
    });
    return false;

    function dats(data) {
      $("#div1").html(data);
      $("#name").val("");
      $("#age").val("");
      $("#post").val("");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the-form" style="width:45%;margin:auto;">
  <form class="form-group formulaire" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="u_name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name">
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" placeholder="your age">
    <textarea name="post" cols="30" id="post" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="bouton" type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: So you're listening at the `#bouton` element for an ajaxStart event -- try `$(document).ajaxStart( $("#bouton").attr(disabled, "disabled") );`

Comment: Is the handler not running or not working?  `disabled` is a property and needs to be set to `true`.  See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/ and also http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2

Comment: @Snowmonkey is correct, `ajaxStart` must be attached to the document (ref: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/).  `disabled` is still a property though :)

Comment: oddly, "disabled" is a true value insofar as javascript is concerned. Any value that is not implicitly false is truthy. But you're absolutely right. And I always forget which one is being phased out, attr or prop. sigh...

Comment: Thanks @Snowmonkey

Comment: Glad to help, @KevinNyawakira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var name, age, post;
    $(".formulaire").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        name = $("#name").val();
        age = $("#age").val();
        post = $("#post").val();
        $("#bouton").attr('disabled','disabled');

        $.post('sequence.php',
            {
                u_name: name,
                age: age,
                post: post
            }, function (data) {
                $("#div1").html(data);
                $("#name").val("");
                $("#age").val("");
                $("#post").val("");
                $("#bouton").removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: The issue with this approach, though, is that the success callback happens after the post has returned -- while the ajaxStart() happens immediately. If you want to make  sure the user can't click a button when the ajax processing is occuring, for example, listening for ajaxStart() will be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

All the handlers for the [JQuery global Ajax events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/), including those added with the `.ajaxStart()` method, must be attached to document.

So you should do something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
     $("#bouton").attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

if you do `$.ajax` everywhere of your code the `ajaxStart` will be fired always for all `ajax` which does not good idea..

As the JQuery document says `$.Post` is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

it is better to use `$.ajax` instead of `$.Post` and handle `.beforeSend` of it like :

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
    $("#bouton").attr('disabled','disabled');
   },
   complete: function(){
      //Completed        
   }
   // ......
 }).done(function() {
    $("#bouton").removeAttr('disabled');
  });
```

Provided test code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var name, age, post;
    $(".formulaire").submit(function(){
        console.clear();
        name=$("#name").val();
        age=$("#age").val();
        post=$("#post").val();
        $.post('sequence.php',
        {
            u_name:name,
            age:age,
            post:post
        },dats
        );  
        return false;
        function dats(data){
            $("#div1").html(data);
            $("#name").val("");
            $("#age").val("");
            $("#post").val("");
        }
    }); 
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("#bouton").attr('disabled','disabled');
  console.log('started...');
}).ajaxStop(function() {
 $("#bouton").removeAttr('disabled');
 console.log('stoped...');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the-form" style="width:45%;margin:auto;">
        <form class="form-group formulaire" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="u_name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name">
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" placeholder="your age">
            <textarea name="post" cols="30" id="post" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="bouton" type="submit" >submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Better how? I mean, I like this approach. I guess that, rather than listening for the global ajaxStart, you'd be listening to the ajax call related directly to this button, which i really prefer. Sigh. Answered my own question. LOL

Comment: I also prefer to handle `ajaxStart` per `ajax` directly, not global handle because, there my be some code which don't need to be run for all ajax send...